# How to make the DolphinDB cluster nodes start automatically on server boot or restart?

Tags: restart, dolphindb, node-cluster

I have deployed a DolphinDB cluster on two servers. The one server is deployed with 1 controller, 1 agent and 2 data nodes, and the other is deployed with 1 agent and 2 data nodes. My operating system is CentOS 8.

I want to make the nodes in the cluster start automatically when the servers are booted up or restarted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller and agents can be set to start automatically using the systemd command.

For detailed instructions, refer to https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/multi_machine_cluster_deployment.md#q2-use-the-systemd-command-to-start-dolphindb-cluster

For the data nodes and compute nodes, configure the parameter *datanodeRestartInterval* in *controller.cfg* or via the Web interface shown as follows:

[image]